# missing : after property id on simple var $props

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get the error:

> missing : after property id

```
var $props = $(this).closest('form').find('[name^="properties"]');
if ($props.length) {
  title = title + '&' + $props.serialize();
}
```

Where is my mistake? I tried a lot but not getting further. The error is on this line:

```
var $props = $(this).closest('form').find('[name^="properties"]');
```

Here is the full function:

```
        initAddToCart: function() {
            if ($('.add-to-cart-btn').length > 0) {
                $('.add-to-cart-btn').click(function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    if ($(this).attr('disabled') != 'disabled') {
                        var productItem = $(this).parents('.product-item');
                        var productId = $(productItem).attr('id');
                        productId = productId.match(/\d+/g);
                        if (!window.ajax_cart) {
                            $('#product-actions-' + productId).submit();
                        } else {
                            var variant_id = $('#product-actions-' + productId + ' select[name=id]').val();
                            if (!variant_id) {
                                variant_id = $('#product-actions-' + productId + ' input[name=id]').val();
                            }
                            var quantity = $('#product-actions-' + productId + ' input[name=quantity]').val();
                            if (!quantity) {
                                quantity = 1;
                            }
                            var title = $(productItem).find('.product-title').html();
                            var image = $(productItem).find('.product-grid-image img').attr('src');

                                                    /* --tim: push line item properties to the ajax add to cart function */

                          var $props = $(this).closest('form').find('[name^="properties"]');
if( $props.length ){
   title = title + '&' + $props.serialize();
}
```

UPDATE:

When I move up the part

```
var $props = $(this).closest('form').find('[name^="properties"]');
```

then I get this error instead

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after formal parameters
```

the console pointing to this error in the lines:

```
if( $props.length ){
   title = title + '&' + $props.serialize();
}
```

Comment: look for code that looks like `obj = { prop = value }` or `{ prop = value; }` or `{ prop; prop2 }` or `{prop prop}` etc./   the code you posted is most likely not the source of your error

Comment: That code works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/sn9agq5f/

Comment: I just added the full function - maybe now its possible to find the error

Comment: I see that you have a object's function method there.  I think you most likely have a syntax error like an unclosed brace or parens, or missing comma, or something similar that is causing it to read something as a property.  Is that code part of an enclosed object?  You might have a typo in there somewhere.  But I can't see it from the code you've posted.  You should try to debug where it actually breaks.

Comment: Does the element with class `add-to-cart-btn` inside the `form` ?

Comment: I don't see any faulty code that would cause that syntax error.  If debugging to where the break happens is too difficult to do, you can try removing blocks of code until you can pinpoint where the error is.  Make sure you have a backup of your code.  _Also, the initAddToCart: should be within the brackets of an object, and there should be a comma right before it or the beginning of the object_

Comment: I just updated the error maybe this helps